# Problem understanding mechanism of select function in c++ socket programming

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, client-server

I take a communication course, and they gave us c++ tcp codes for client and server, where the client asks what the time is, and the server responds. The server can maintain multiple connections with multiple clients. The server contains a data structure called socketState, which contains data about a specific socket so it will be saved even after fd_set clears its memomory:

```
struct SocketState
{
    SOCKET id;          // Socket handle
    int recv;           // Receiving?
    int send;           // Sending?
    int sendSubType;    // Sending sub-type
    char buffer[128];
    int len;
}
```

The server has an array of 60 elements of this type, and seperate functions to add or remove a socket from this array by updating the relevant fields of the relevant element, and functions to accept new connections, and to send/receive messages.

The server code is:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
# include <ctime>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <assert.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

struct SocketState
{
    SOCKET id;          // Socket handle
    int recv;           // Receiving?
    int send;           // Sending?
    int sendSubType;    // Sending sub-type
    char buffer[128];
    int len;
};

const int TIME_PORT = 27015;
const int MAX_SOCKETS = 60;
const int EMPTY = 0;
const int LISTEN = 1;
const int RECEIVE = 2;
const int IDLE = 3;
const int SEND = 4;
const int SEND_TIME = 1;
const int SEND_SECONDS = 2;

bool addSocket(SOCKET id, int what);
void removeSocket(int index);
void acceptConnection(int index);
void receiveMessage(int index);
void sendMessage(int index);

struct SocketState sockets[MAX_SOCKETS] = { 0 };
int socketsCount = 0;


void main()
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    if (NO_ERROR != WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData))
    {
        cout << "Time Server: Error at WSAStartup()\n";
        return;
    }

    SOCKET listenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);


    if (INVALID_SOCKET == listenSocket)
    {
        cout << "Time Server: Error at socket(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    sockaddr_in serverService;

    serverService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverService.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverService.sin_port = htons(TIME_PORT);

    if (SOCKET_ERROR == bind(listenSocket, (SOCKADDR*)& serverService, sizeof(serverService)))
    {
        cout << "Time Server: Error at bind(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    if (SOCKET_ERROR == listen(listenSocket, 5))
    {
        cout << "Time Server: Error at listen(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(listenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    addSocket(listenSocket, LISTEN);



    while (true)
    {
        fd_set waitRecv;
        FD_ZERO(&waitRecv);
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SOCKETS; i++)
        {
            if ((sockets[i].recv == LISTEN) || (sockets[i].recv == RECEIVE))
                FD_SET(sockets[i].id, &waitRecv);
        }


        fd_set waitSend;
        FD_ZERO(&waitSend);
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SOCKETS; i++)
        {
            if (sockets[i].send == SEND)
                FD_SET(sockets[i].id, &waitSend);
        }

        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 15;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;
        int nfd = select(0, &waitRecv, &waitSend, NULL, NULL);
        if (nfd == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "Time Server: Error at select(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SOCKETS && nfd > 0; i++)
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(sockets[i].id, &waitRecv))
            {
                nfd--;
                switch (sockets[i].recv)
                {
                case LISTEN:
                    acceptConnection(i);
                    break;

                case RECEIVE:
                    receiveMessage(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SOCKETS && nfd > 0; i++)
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(sockets[i].id, &waitSend))
            {
                nfd--;
                switch (sockets[i].send)
                {
                case SEND:
                    sendMessage(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    // Closing connections and Winsock.
    cout << "Time Server: Closing Connection.\n";
    closesocket(listenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
}

bool addSocket(SOCKET id, int what)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SOCKETS; i++)
    {
        if (sockets[i].recv == EMPTY)
        {
            sockets[i].id = id;
            sockets[i].recv = what;
            sockets[i].send = IDLE;
            sockets[i].len = 0;
            socketsCount++;
            return (true);
        }
    }
    return (false);
}

void removeSocket(int index)
{
    sockets[index].recv = EMPTY;
    sockets[index].send = EMPTY;
    socketsCount--;
}

void acceptConnection(int index)
{
    SOCKET id = sockets[index].id;
    struct sockaddr_in from;        // Address of sending partner
    int fromLen = sizeof(from);

    SOCKET msgSocket = accept(id, (struct sockaddr*) & from, &fromLen);
    if (INVALID_SOCKET == msgSocket)
    {
        cout << "Time Server: Error at accept(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "Time Server: Client " << inet_ntoa(from.sin_addr) << ":" << ntohs(from.sin_port) << " is connected." << endl;

    //
    // Set the socket to be in non-blocking mode.
    //
    unsigned long flag = 1;
    if (ioctlsocket(msgSocket, FIONBIO, &flag) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Time Server: Error at ioctlsocket(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }

    if (addSocket(msgSocket, RECEIVE) == false)
    {
        cout << "\t\tToo many connections, dropped!\n";
        closesocket(id);
    }
    return;
}

void receiveMessage(int index)
{
    SOCKET msgSocket = sockets[index].id;

    int len = sockets[index].len;
    int bytesRecv = recv(msgSocket, &sockets[index].buffer[len], sizeof(sockets[index].buffer) - len, 0);

    if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesRecv)
    {
        cout << "Time Server: Error at recv(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(msgSocket);
        removeSocket(index);
        return;
    }
    if (bytesRecv == 0)
    {
        closesocket(msgSocket);
        removeSocket(index);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        sockets[index].buffer[len + bytesRecv] = '\0'; //add the null-terminating to make it a string
        cout << "Time Server: Recieved: " << bytesRecv << " bytes of \"" << &sockets[index].buffer[len] << "\" message.\n";

        sockets[index].len += bytesRecv;

        if (sockets[index].len > 0)
        {
            if (strncmp(sockets[index].buffer, "TimeString", 10) == 0)
            {
                sockets[index].send = SEND;
                sockets[index].sendSubType = SEND_TIME;
                memcpy(sockets[index].buffer, &sockets[index].buffer[10], sockets[index].len - 10);
                sockets[index].len -= 10;
                return;
            }
            else if (strncmp(sockets[index].buffer, "SecondsSince1970", 16) == 0)
            {
                sockets[index].send = SEND;
                sockets[index].sendSubType = SEND_SECONDS;
                memcpy(sockets[index].buffer, &sockets[index].buffer[16], sockets[index].len - 16);
                sockets[index].len -= 16;
                return;
            }
            else if (strncmp(sockets[index].buffer, "Exit", 4) == 0)
            {
                closesocket(msgSocket);
                removeSocket(index);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}

void sendMessage(int index)
{
    int bytesSent = 0;
    char sendBuff[255];

    SOCKET msgSocket = sockets[index].id;
    if (sockets[index].sendSubType == SEND_TIME)
    {
        // Answer client's request by the current time string.

        // Get the current time.
        time_t timer;
        time(&timer);
        // Parse the current time to printable string.
        strcpy(sendBuff, ctime(&timer));
        sendBuff[strlen(sendBuff) - 1] = 0; //to remove the new-line from the created string
    }
    else if (sockets[index].sendSubType == SEND_SECONDS)
    {
        // Answer client's request by the current time in seconds.

        // Get the current time.
        time_t timer;
        time(&timer);
        // Convert the number to string.
        _itoa((int)timer, sendBuff, 10);
    }
    bytesSent = send(msgSocket, sendBuff, (int)strlen(sendBuff), 0);
    if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesSent)
    {
        cout << "Time Server: Error at send(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        return;
    }

    cout << "Time Server: Sent: " << bytesSent << "\\" << strlen(sendBuff) << " bytes of \"" << sendBuff << "\" message.\n";

    sockets[index].send = IDLE;
}
```

And this is my client code:

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <winsock2.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
# include <ctime>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <assert.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

const int TIME_PORT = 27015;


void main()
{

    // Initialize Winsock (Windows Sockets).

    WSAData wsaData;
    if (NO_ERROR != WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData))
    {
        cout << "Time Client: Error at WSAStartup()\n";
        return;
    }

    // Client side:
    // Create a socket and connect to an internet address.

    SOCKET connSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (INVALID_SOCKET == connSocket)
    {
        cout << "Time Client: Error at socket(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_port = htons(TIME_PORT);

    if (SOCKET_ERROR == connect(connSocket, (SOCKADDR*)& server, sizeof(server)))
    {
        cout << "Time Client: Error at connect(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(connSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }


    // Send and receive data.

    int bytesSent = 0;
    int bytesRecv = 0;
    char sendBuff[255];
    char recvBuff[255];
    int option = 0;

    while (option != 3)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease choose an option:\n";
        cout << "1 - Get current time.\n";
        cout << "2 - Get current time in seconds.\n";
        cout << "3 - Exit.\n";
        cout << ">> ";

        cin >> option;

        if (option == 1)
            strcpy(sendBuff, "TimeString");
        else if (option == 2)
            strcpy(sendBuff, "SecondsSince1970");
        else if (option == 3)
            strcpy(sendBuff, "Exit");

        bytesSent = send(connSocket, sendBuff, (int)strlen(sendBuff), 0);
        if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesSent)
        {
            cout << "Time Client: Error at send(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            closesocket(connSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
        cout << "Time Client: Sent: " << bytesSent << "/" << strlen(sendBuff) << " bytes of \"" << sendBuff << "\" message.\n";

        // Gets the server's answer for options 1 and 2.
        if (option == 1 || option == 2)
        {
            bytesRecv = recv(connSocket, recvBuff, 255, 0);
            if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesRecv)
            {
                cout << "Time Client: Error at recv(): " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                closesocket(connSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return;
            }
            if (bytesRecv == 0)
            {
                cout << "Server closed the connection\n";
                return;
            }

            recvBuff[bytesRecv] = '\0'; //add the null-terminating to make it a string
            cout << "Time Client: Recieved: " << bytesRecv << " bytes of \"" << recvBuff << "\" message.\n";
        }
        else if (option == 3)
        {
            // Closing connections and Winsock.
            cout << "Time Client: Closing Connection.\n";
            closesocket(connSocket);
            WSACleanup();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, my main problem is that whenever I send a message from a client or clients through the command prompt of windows, or from Putty, or staright from Visiual Studio code of the client, the select function keeps blocking ( Except when I use timeout, but then it returns 0 ), and I can't really figure out why. I guess it's a basic understanding problem of the machainism of select, even though I read about the function in number of sources.
Also when I try to connect the server through "telnet port number" command on cmd, I just get a blank black screen.

In the documentation of select it says first argument is ignored. But as far as I know, it represents the number of socket handles the fdset can monitor. Then how in spite of it i can have an access to this attribute? Or maybe I don't need to, and there's another solution to the blocking state?

If someone can help I would be grateful.

Comment: This exact question was posted 3h ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734175/problem-understanding-mechanism-of-select-function-in-c-socket-programming

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes wrong link (now corrected) but it was deleted by OP

Comment: Indeed. I posted it then, and also now because the problem has not been solved yet.

Comment: The first parameter to `select` is supposed to be the maximum value of any file descriptor you have a bit set for. In a pinch you can just pass in `FD_SETSIZE - 1`, but that may make it less efficient.

Comment: @OriLev - Why do you think it's ignored? None of the Linux documentation I'm reading says it's ignored. The code behind all that originally came from BSD Unix, where it also isn't ignored. Is there Windows specific documentation that says it is? Even if Windows ignores it, you shouldn't rely on that because nothing else does. Oh, I see, for Winsock, it is. Still you shouldn't do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-select

Comment: @OriLev Please do not repost questions. [Read here instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer) on how to get attention to your unanswered question

Comment: @Omnifarious  Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-select

Comment: @Omnifarious Anyway, I passed FD_SETSIZE - 1, and it still continues

Comment: @OriLev - I'm not sure where your problem is. There is nothing obvious that jumps out at me while reading the code. I do not, and refuse to have a Windows system. So in order to properly debug it, I'd have to translate it a bit to make it run on Linux, then debug it. I will say that your code is very poorly designed C++. It's an OK design for C though.

Comment: @Omnifarious That's because this course does not require knowledge in c++, only in c.

Comment: You need to narrow down your problem in the code yourself. Learn how to use a debugger, verify the arguments to `select` call.